# How do i assign priority level in TCP packet

Tags: tcp

i have a question.
 three senders are attached with one receiver.
The sender A has high priority 1
The sender B has Medium priority 0.6
The sender c has low priority 0.2
i want to transfer these priority to receiver side.
how i can, if my work is based on TCP layer?

Comment: in what environment? a switch? does the switch have options for this?  linux machine?

Comment: Your question is very vague. Are you just trying to pass information? Or are you expecting these priorities to do something? If so, what?

Comment: All nodes are ad-hoc, and want work in opnet simulator.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz. i will use these priority value at receiver side for assignment of bandwidth. i want to assign bandwidth based on sender priority values

Answer (score 1):

1. Develop a protocol for communicating the priorities over the TCP link. It can be as simple as text, like "0.2", with a terminating newline or zero byte.
2. Implement the protocol in both the sender and the receiver, so the receiver knows the priorities.
3. In the receiver, use the priority however you think is appropriate. For example, if multiple connections are ready to read, perhaps read from the highest priority connection.

Comment: Can i use existing packet format? e.g in network layer ToS (Type of service) is available for assignment of priorties

Comment: @Sohaib It's hard to say without understanding your use case. This is the simplest method that meets the requirements you've stated so far, which are: 1) The sender knows the priorities. 2) The receiver needs to use the priorities to allocate bandwidth.

Comment: My protocol perform three steps 1) Its calculate each sender node priority  value 2) sender node sent priority value to receiver and 3) receiver uses these priority values for setting of advertisement window. for more understanding please check this paper http://infocom2003.ieee-infocom.org/papers/28_03.PDF

Comment: You will see Fig. 1, in reciever side this paper use user preferences